# ZSH list completions after unambiguously tab-completing a directory

Tags: zsh

Better shown through example, here is the desired behaviour:

~/documents/doc1.txt, ~/documents/doc2.txt, and ~/downloads exist.

The user types:

```
vim ~/doc<TAB>
```

Because this completion is not ambiguous (there are no other completions that start with doc),  it is expanded to ~/documents/ however in ADDITION, another tab-completion is done automatically afterwards, so after the first tab the user sees:

```
vim ~/documents/
doc1.txt doc2.txt
```

Essentially where the user would normally have to press tab twice here, now they only need to press it once.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a plugin called `zsh-autocomplete`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) that does exactly that: It automatically shows your next level of choices whenever you tab-complete part of a path.

In fact, it does this not only for paths, but for all completions. And you don't even have to press Tab first; it will show possible completion options already while you are still typing. Please view the demo on the page linked above to see what I'm talking about.